# Enable CORS on IIS for all sites hosted on server

Tags: iis, cors

I've installed the CORS IIS module (v 1.0) and am able to get it to work on a single site by modifying the site's web.config with something like this.

```
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
        <add origin="https://*.example.com"> 
        </add>
    </cors>
```

Instead of adding this to every web.config for each site, how can I make this change once and have it apply to all sites hosted on the server?

Comment: As the values of `origin` vary by sites, it is impossible to use the same rule on all sites.

Comment: If all sites hosted have the same domain but different subdomains, there is no way to set this once so that all subdomains are allowed? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of adding this to every web.config for each site, how can I make this change once and have it apply to all sites hosted on the server?

As far as I know,  we could enable, disable CORS for a whole IIS server or for a specific IIS site, an application, a virtual directory, a physical directory or a file (system.webServer/cors).

If you want to enable the CROS for the whole site in IIS, I suggest you could modify the applicationhost.config's web.server tag. This will enable the whole site with CORS.

Path:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\

Details, you could refer to below config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
        <add origin="*" />
        <add origin="https://*.microsoft.com"
             allowCredentials="true"
             maxAge="120"> 
            <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
                <add header="header1" />
                <add header="header2" />
            </allowHeaders>
            <allowMethods>
                 <add method="DELETE" />
            </allowMethods>
            <exposeHeaders>
                <add header="header1" />
                <add header="header2" />
            </exposeHeaders>
        </add>
        <add origin="http://*" allowed="false" />
    </cors>
</system.webServer>
```